# Wordpress Post page list view seems broken

Tags: posts

The post list page in the backend admin for my wordpress seems broken. The post title and other details are broken down every character. I have not modified any css or theme file. Anyone has any idea why this might be happening? Please see the attached image.

[image: Broken Post list in admin panel]

Comment: It looks like you're using several plugins that customise the list. I would start deactivating those so that you can identify which one is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try hiding some columns by pulling down the Screen Options drawer and unchecking a few.

If that doesn't work, then follow Jacob Peattie's recommendation on deactivating plugins.

[image: Posts list table]